# Problema com postgresql server version mismatch

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou tentando restaurar uma base, pequena , realizo o backup na minha máquina na versão 9.6 , mas, alega erro ao tentar criar o backup via pgadmin III,
executo através de um bat :

> ```
> pg_dump.exe -h localhost -p 5432 -U Nome  -n protocolo -F c -b -v -f "C:\Elotech\Backup\bkp_protocolo_hoje_%dataAtual%.backup" nome_base
> ```

Mas, infelizmente não consigo executar na máquina do cliente sendo que lá utiliza uma versão bem antiga 9.1

--Alega erro de cabeçalho.

Como faço para conseguir restaurar no cliente ?

Comment: Poderia adicionar a mensagem de erro na pergunta e o comando que está utilizando para restaurar?

Comment: Praticamente todas as suas perguntas estão em aberto. acesse o [Tour] e veja como participar da comunidade